# How to use media query with div as screen for mobile preview in desktop website?

Tags: html, mobile, media-queries, screen-size

I need to show a preview of the code responsive in a div that has the size of a mobile phone, how can I use media queries?
or i can do it with jquery?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTML

```
<iframe src="link-to-the-site-you-want-to-demo.html"></iframe>
```

CSS

```
iframe{ /*your phone dimensions here*/
    height:640px;
    width:320px;
}
```